# Why is repeated vertices allowed in Euler path?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) defines path as:

> A path is a trail in which all vertices (except possibly the first and
>   last) are distinct.

if we cannot repeat a vertex in a path then how can we repeat it in Euler path ? ( which is a path in which every edge is visited exactly once )

For example:

[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnM2X.png)

In the above graph A-B-C-D-E-F-C-A-F is an Euler path but as you can see A, F and C vertices are visited twice which is not allowed in a path then how can you say its a path ?

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Apparently, the appropriate term would then be [Eulerian trail (or walk)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli so calling it "Euler path" is wrong ??

Comment: I’ve always heard it called an Eulerian trail. A quick google search has showed that “Eulerian path” is pretty common though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the terminology of graph theory has not yet been standardized. Some people use the term "paths" for what should be called trails, and "simple paths" for honest-to-goodness paths; so naturally those misguided souls use "Euler path" and "Euler cycle" for what are rightly called "Euler trails" and "Euler circuits".

Answer (score 1):

An 'eulerian path' need not be a 'path'. As already mentioned by someone, the exact term should be eulerian trail. The example given in the question itself clarifies this fact. The trail given in the example is an 'eulerian path', but not a path. But it is a trail certainly. So, if a trail is an eulerian path, that does not mean that it should be a path at the first place.